# Action Listener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jradiobutton

The below code is an action listener for a project.  Basically, I have 4 radio buttons and when I click one, I want it to change a variable on screen.  When I run the code, it is simply adding together all the values.  Are there any other ways to do this?

```
class Calc implements ActionListener
    {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
     {
       double base = 0.00;
       double options;
       double total;

      if (Button25.isSelected());
      {
      base = base + 999.99;
      String base2 = Double.toString(base);
      lblBaseAns.setText(base2);
      }

      if (Button32.isSelected());
      {
        base = base + 1049.99;
        String base2 = Double.toString(base);
        lblBaseAns.setText(base2);
      }

      if (Button35.isSelected());
      {
        base = base + 1099.99;
        String base2 = Double.toString(base);
        lblBaseAns.setText(base2);
      }

      if (Button42.isSelected());
      {
        base = base + 1155.99;
        String base2 = Double.toString(base);
        lblBaseAns.setText(base2);
      }


     }
    }
```

Comment: "*adding together all the values*". How?

Comment: I don't know why, but when I do an action that triggers the code, it adds all of the values from each radio button together and displays it.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. You're probably missing something about the **group**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, for each `if()` statement, such as **if (Button32.isSelected());**, you have a `;` symbol at the end. This shouldn't be there. Here is the corrected code...

```
class Calc implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        double base = 0.00;
        double options;
        double total;

        if (Button25.isSelected()){ // changed
            base = base + 999.99;
            String base2 = Double.toString(base);
            lblBaseAns.setText(base2);
        }
        else if (Button32.isSelected()){ // changed
            base = base + 1049.99;
            String base2 = Double.toString(base);
            lblBaseAns.setText(base2);
        }
        else if (Button35.isSelected()){ // changed
            base = base + 1099.99;
            String base2 = Double.toString(base);
            lblBaseAns.setText(base2);
        }
        else if (Button42.isSelected()){ // changed
            base = base + 1155.99;
            String base2 = Double.toString(base);
            lblBaseAns.setText(base2);
        }
    }
}
```

As an alternative, why don't you get the button that was clicked from the `ActionEvent`, and then use the button in your if-else branch...

```
class Calc implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        double base = 0.00;
        double options;
        double total;

        Object clickedObject = event.getSource();
        if (clickedObject instanceof JRadioButton){
            JRadioButton clickedButton = (JRadioButton)clickedObject;

            if (clickedButton == Button25){
                base = base + 999.99;
                String base2 = Double.toString(base);
                lblBaseAns.setText(base2);
            }
            else if (clickedButton == Button32){
                base = base + 1049.99;
                String base2 = Double.toString(base);
                lblBaseAns.setText(base2);
            }
            else if (clickedButton == Button35){
                base = base + 1099.99;
                String base2 = Double.toString(base);
                lblBaseAns.setText(base2);
            }
            else if (clickedButton == Button42){
                base = base + 1155.99;
                String base2 = Double.toString(base);
                lblBaseAns.setText(base2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I totally didn't even notice the ; error.  As soon as I fixed this it solved the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: I didn't notice it either, until I went to write my code suggestion.